# What are recommended resources for learning query/view design in MySQL Workbench for a long-time MS Access user?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, mysql-workbench

I've used MS Access for over 20 years, and have used MySQL sporadically. I now have MySQL Server and MySQL Workbench running (the latest Community versions for Ubuntu) and am using it more and more.

I am comfortable with creating queries, reports etc in Access.

So what are some good resources recommendations for someone learning to use MySQL Workbench to create views, write SQL statements, etc who has used Access and is comfortable with databases?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This kind of question does not fit well in the Q&A format of this site, so it will likely get closed. Your best bet is any of the search machines to come up with a tutorial for switchers and something like that.

Comment: Yeah well thought I'd try my luck anyway. I have been googling and found this - https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/a-guide-for-migrating-from-microsoft-access-to-mysql/ - but looking for recommendations from live human beings who've done switching / migrating along the same path.